# access an argument in a string pointer char*

Tags: c

I need to try and fix sentences from an input in c, so I tried separating tokens and making new strings and then I wanted to access the first char of each string and make it a capital letter.

Now I am having trouble understanding how to access only one char of each new string, like trying to access only 'e' in hello which is in str1[0] second char.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void main()
{
    char str1[601], * str2[601];
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    printf_s("*************** Welcome to the text cleaner ***************\n\n");
    printf_s("Please enter text:\n");
    gets_s(str1, sizeof(str1));
    char* sentence=NULL,*next_sentence=NULL;
    
        sentence = strtok_s(str1,".",&next_sentence);

        while (sentence != NULL)
        {
            printf(" %s\n", sentence);
            str2[i++] = sentence;
            sentence = strtok_s(NULL, ".", &next_sentence); 
        }
        str2[i++] = '\0';
        printf_s("%s", str2[1]);
}
```

[Code and content of variables in debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zl1vE.png)

Comment: Removed the image, we don't need it. Add sample inputs and expected output for this problem. You just want to capitalise first letter of each sentence in a text? Note that sentences can also end with `?` `!` along with `.`.

Comment: @जलजनक your edit also removed the content of variables visible in the screenshot. That removes information from the post which should not happen.

Comment: I do only need that, but if someone could explain how to access each char in the new str2[] ,that woukd be my main concern

Comment: `str2[i++] = '\0';` This is confusion. While it is strictly valid, it creates the impression you would deal with characters. Instead you assign a 0-value to a pointer variable. You should use `NULL` instead.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want access `str2[0][1]`. `str2[0]` points to `"hello"` and second character `str2[0][1]` contains `'e'`.

Comment: @Gerhardh restored image link to code (variable values).

Comment: Maybe what you want is to see that `e` (and the whole string) n the debugger (Because you added screenshot including variable view in debugger). That is not possible because the type of `str2[0]` is only `char*` without any length indication.

Comment: when i tried that ,microsoft visual studio window pop up,which sais no sybol loaded @Gerhardh

Comment: When you tried what?

Comment: when i tried to print str2[0][1] to see what i get

Comment: How did you try? When did the error happen? "No symbol loaded" sounds like an error in debugger. Anyway that should not happen with that code.

Comment: it kind of works now only get a waring , i think you can close

Comment: "no symbol loaded" sound like you compiled it without debugging information enabled. In gcc you need to add `-g` or better `-ggdb`. I don't know how to do that in Visual Studio.

Answer (score -1):

Here is my take on what you are trying to do.  I'm showing the code and the results.  I have simplified your effort since you are mixing printf and printf_s.  You use the _s variant for buffer overflow control.  That does not seem to be your concern while simply learning about arrays.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void main() {
    char str1[601];  // This is an array of chars. 
                     // If storing a string, final elem is 0x0
    char *str2[601]; // This is a pointer to an array of chars.
                     //
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    // I removed your _s variants of standard libraries.  Let's keep
    // things simple.
    printf("*************** Welcome to the text cleaner ***************\n\n");
    printf("Please enter text:\n");
    // ditto for gets to fgets
    //
    // Excerpt rom the manpage
    //
    // char *fgets(char *s, int size, FILE *stream);
    //
    // fgets()  reads in at most one less than size characters from 
    // stream and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s.  
    // Reading stops after an EOF or a newline.  If a newline is read,
    // it is stored into the buffer.  A terminating null byte ('\0') 
    // is stored after the  last  character  in  the buffer.
    //
    // fgets() returns s on success, and NULL on error or when end of 
    // file occurs while no characters have been read.
    //str1 = fgets(str1, sizeof(str1), stdin);
    // I would do a null check here.
    if (NULL == fgets(str1, sizeof(str1), stdin)) {
      return; // graceful exit
    }
    // Notice on the bracket print of your text, the closing >
    // is shown on the next line.  This is because its capturing the
    // newline/carriage return character. 
    printf("You entered %d chars and the text was:\n<%s>\n", strlen(str1), str1);

    // These are for your strtok operation
    // I would call them tokens or words, but
    // whatever.
    char *sentence=NULL;
    char *next_sentence=NULL;

    // wants to parse a string
    // Excerpt from manpage
    //
    // char *strtok(char *str, const char *delim);
    // Ahh, now I see why you name is sentence.  You
    // are looking for periods to separage sentences.
    printf("Lets use strtok\n");

    sentence = strtok(str1, ".");

    while (sentence != NULL) {
        printf("A sentence is:\n %s\n", sentence);
        str2[i++] = sentence;
        sentence = strtok(NULL, "."); 
    }

    // So now, your individual sentences are stored
    // in the array str2.
    // str2[0] is the first sentence.
    // str2[1] is the next sentence.
    //
    // To access the characters, specify a sentence and
    // then specify the character.
    // 
    // You can do the math, but do a man ascii, look at
    // difference in lowercase a and uppercase A in terms
    // of ascii.  If its not captializ3ed already, simply
    // add that offset or error out if not in set a-z.
    //
    // Here I will just make the first letter of the second
    // sentence to be J.
    str2[1][0] = 'J';
    // Note, since you are going to have in the 'space'
    // since you are delimitting on '.', It will have the
    // effect of replacing 'space' with 'J'.
    printf("Sentence two is: \n%s\n", str2[1]);
}
```

Here is the code in action.

```
*************** Welcome to the text cleaner ***************

Please enter text:
John was here. and here.
You entered 25 chars and the text was:
<John was here. and here.
>
Lets use strtok
A sentence is:
 John was here
A sentence is:
  and here
A sentence is:
 

Sentence two is: 
Jand here
```

I hope that helps.  TLDR use str2[x][y] to access a string x at character y.